# Get taxonomy term field value?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have some taxonomy terms that have an image field in them. I am trying to get the value of the image field in my templates. How can I do this? The field's name is `field_header_image`.

I have this so far but it does not work..

```
$headerimg = field_view_field('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image'); 
print render($headerimg);
```

I'm guessing I need something else for `taxonomy_term` but I'm not sure what that should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get it like this :

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$field_header_image = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image');
if ($field_header_image) {
  $headerimg = field_view_value('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image', $field_header_image[0], array('type' => 'image'));
}
print render($headerimg);
```

If you want to use an image_style :

```
$headerimg = field_view_value('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image', $field_header_image[0], array(
  'type' => 'image',
  'settings' => array(
    'image_style' => 'my_image_style', //place your image style here
  ),
));
```

Here is a contextual answer if you are on your taxonomy term page.

In your file `template.php` use the `theme_preprocess_page` function like this :

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
  if ($term) {
    $field_header_image = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image');
    if ($field_header_image) {
      $vars['headerimg'] = field_view_value('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image', $field_header_image[0], array('type' => 'image'));
    }
  }
}
```

Then in you `page.tpl.php` you can `print render($headerimg);`

Comment: field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image') does not return anything for me. It just generates an error that says "Error. The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Comment: how do you get your `$term` object ? You need to have taxonomy_term_load or something before. Can you check the Drupal logs ?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just using some example code that I found. I've never done this before.

Comment: I edited my answer, all you need to have is the tid. PLMK if you have some errors (Drupal Logs would help)

Comment: Ok here are the errors in the log...

EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term.

Notice: Undefined variable: tid in include()

Comment: If it helps at all I'm trying to do this on the term's page. For example I have a vocab named Animals with terms such as Dog, Cat, Monkey. Each term has an image uploaded to it that i'd like to display on their page. For example, the dog term should display a dog image.

Comment: What's the name of the template you want to print your image ?

Comment: it is the page.tpl.php template

Comment: Ok I edited my answer for your specific case (at the end). Can you confirm me that in you url you get something like this (if not rewritted) : `taxonomy/term/3` (3 is just an example)

Comment: Thank you! The theme_preprocess_page() function did the trick. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you. Don't forget to add a condition if you have many vocabularies ;-)